# SimpleInjector: End-to-end testing of controller's methods on a test database

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, simple-injector

I have a web app with several REST API controllers. This controllers got injected repositories as per [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/testing-and-debugging/unit-testing-controllers-in-web-api#testing-actions-that-return-httpresponsemessage) using SimpleInjector. I'd like to add some end-to-end testing to my project to make sure controller's method calls affect database in predictable manner (I'm using EF6, MySQL, code first). I was going to use [this plan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40949708/2782477) to test my app. I like overall approach but it seems like in this approach author is feeding db context directly into controller. In my case I have a Controller that gets an injected Repository from constructor and in turn Repositiry gets injected DbContext. Obviously I can hardcode the chain of creating DbContext, instantiating Repository followed by instantiating a Controller but it kinda defies the purpose of using the SimpleInjector, isn't it? I think there should be the way do it in more transparrent manner.

Basically I would like to inject separate database into my tests. When server is running it's using one database, when tests are running they are using the other ad-hoc database.

I have my test classes in a separate project, so I will need a way to instantiate my Controllers and Repositories from the main project. I'm not sure how I can do it either. Is it a good idea to expose my `SimpleInjector.Container` from another project somehow?

Additional info: I'm using .Net Framework (non-Core), I would like to manage withouth mocking for now unless it's required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can abstract the `DbContext` behind an interface and use SimpleInjector's option to override registrations for your tests. That will allow you to register a different implementation of your context for testing. Then in your test setup code call your standarad registrations, assuming they're all in your composition root and/or bootstrapping projedct. Then flip the override switch and register the test context.

[Override Registrations](http://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/howto.html#override-existing-registrations) 
 - For testing only

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this out.

Answer (score 2):

In your case, I would expect you to don't have to do anything in particular. Your end-to-end tests would call into a test version of the web application over HTTP, and this test application is *configured* with a connection string that points at a test database. This way you can use the exact same DI configuration, without having to do any changes. You certainly don't want to inject a different `DbContext` during testing.

Another option is to test in-memory, which means you don't call the web application over HTTP, but instead request a controller directly from Simple Injector and call its methods. Here the same holds: the only thing you want to change is your connection string, which is something that should already be configurable.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Well, it's not exactly an end-to-end tests as I won't be sending any HTTP requests, even though I will consider doing it now when you've mentioned it. I was going to test it by instantiating a controller and calling its methods. Ideally I would like tests to run in parallel and on a clear database each time and on the same DB server version (= no in-memory for me). I plan to generate guid name for a schema for each test and remoe this shcema in teardown. Therefore I need to have different constructors for DbContext on usual and test versions.

Comment: In that case, build a new Container instance for each test and go with JSteward's answer.